# iOs show checkmark when finished loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an implanted Facebook in my app. When it is posting something on Facebook it is displaying a Activity Indicator wich works as it should but I want to show a checkmark when it is finished with posting. I am not sure how to do this. This is the code when it is finished with loading

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

//Stop the spinner
[ActivityView removeView];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at  - https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

It is very easy to use and has many examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a XIB, place the checkmark in an imageView and then position it where you want in your view. Wire it to an IBOutlet so you can access it from your view controller. Set the imageView's property to be hidden initially.

In your didReceiveResponseMethod, update the imageView's property to:

```
imageView.hidden = NO;
```